# Typescript error: "./src/models/MenuModel").SortOrder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345) (property) MenuModel.order: SortOrder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting, binary-search

error on line:

```
98
/src/models/MenuModel").SortOrder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)
this: this
120
Type 'number | SortState[]' is not assignable to type 'SortState[]'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SortState[]'.ts(2322)
(property) MenuModel.solution: SortState[]
```

Tried adding a binary search algorithm to my sortingAlgorithm class for visualization but getting error messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.